# Dúvidas sobre pastas no ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Estou com dúvida sobre o que significa cada pasta do projeto. Alguém poderia me explicar resumidamente? Gostaria de saber também, sobre o **omnisharp**.

**PASTAS:**

**obj**

**pages**

**properties**

**wwwroot**

**appsettings**

**csproj**

**program.cs**

**startup.cs**

Comment: [Este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79UWvR734wI) fala um pouco sobre essa estrutura de pastas que você mostra na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é o caso, mas essa estrutura de pastas parece ter sido retirada do template `Web Application (Razor pages)` do Visual Studio.

Neste caso:
*obj*: Serve para o compilador armazenar objetos temporários utilizados na compilação

*pages*: Serve para armazenar os arquivos *.cshtml (e *.cs associados), ou basicamente as páginas do seu site.

*properties*: É um diretório do Visual Studio, para armazenar alguns arquivos de configuração do projeto.

*wwwroot*: Serve para conteúdo estático, como arquivos HTML, CSS e JS.

*appsettings*: Não é um diretório, mas sim um arquivo json, onde ficam as configurações do seu site.

*csproj*: Não é um diretório, mas sim o arquivo de projeto do seu site. Nele são especificadas as dependências e outras configurações. É semelhante ao `package.json`, no node.

*program.cs*: Também não é um diretório. É onde geralmente está o endtrypoint (ou "main") do seu site.

*startup.cs*: Também não é um diretório. É um arquivo comumente utilizado para configurar a inicialização do site, bem como a pipeline de execução do asp.net.

---

O `omnisharp` por já merecia outra resposta... Trata-se de um conjunto de plugins e extensões para os editores mais utilizados para facilitar o desenvolvimento de aplicações .Net. Até onde sei, um dos principais objetivos do mesmo é forcener ferramentas de refatoração para agilizar o desenvolvimento.

Comment: Esqueci de responder sobre o Omnisharp. Vou editar a resposta :)

Comment: Muito obrigado @tvdias. Me ajudou bastante no entendimento.

Comment: Olá @allanalencar, aconselho seguir o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver a melhor forma de agradecer por uma resposta :)

Comment: Ok. publiquei outra dúvida. [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/260256)

Comment: Por acaso também respondi à sua outra pergunta...

Comment: @AllanAlencar, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita, caso ache a explicação satisfatória.

Comment: onde marco a resposta? vou fazer o tour novamente. Sou novo aqui e estou aprendendo.

Comment: Tem mais info neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), @AllanAlencar